# How to calculate the diff between dates using a condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to find out how many days a user do not buy a product,

I have the following DF:

```
ID|  DATA     |  QTD
1 |2019-01-31 |   NA
1 |2019-02-28 |   3
1 |2019-03-31 |   NA
1 |2019-04-30 |   5
2 |2019-01-31 |   3
2 |2019-02-28 |   4
2 |2019-03-31 |   NA
2 |2019-04-30 |   NA
3 |2019-01-31 |   NA
3 |2019-02-28 |   3
3 |2019-03-31 |   NA
3 |2019-04-30 |   NA
```

I'm trying to use dplyr:mutate, but don't getting any result.

My objective:

```
ID|  DATA     |  QTD  | Days
1 |2019-01-31 |   NA  |  NA
1 |2019-02-28 |   3   |  0
1 |2019-03-31 |   NA  |  31
1 |2019-04-30 |   5   |  0
2 |2019-01-31 |   3   |  0
2 |2019-02-28 |   4   |  0
2 |2019-03-31 |   NA  |  31
2 |2019-04-30 |   NA  |  61
3 |2019-01-31 |   NA  |  NA
3 |2019-02-28 |   NA  |  NA 
3 |2019-03-31 |   4   |  31
3 |2019-04-30 |   8   |  61
```

Tks

Comment: 1) post reproducible data using, e.g., `dput(head(df))`, and 2), show the code you used (not just "I tried `dplyr::mutate`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(DATA = as.Date(DATA, "%Y-%m-%d"),
         QTD = as.numeric(as.character(QTD))) %>% 
  group_by(ID,
           ID2 = cumsum(+(if_else(is.na(QTD), 0, QTD) != 0))) %>% 
  mutate(NoBuy = cumsum(replace_na(
                                as.numeric(if_else(is.na(QTD), DATA - lag(DATA), 0))
                        , 0))) %>% 
  ungroup %>% select(-ID2)

#> Warning: NAs introduced by coercion
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>       ID DATA         QTD NoBuy
#>    <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1 2019-01-31    NA     0
#>  2     1 2019-02-28     3     0
#>  3     1 2019-03-31    NA    31
#>  4     1 2019-04-30     5     0
#>  5     2 2019-01-31     3     0
#>  6     2 2019-02-28     4     0
#>  7     2 2019-03-31    NA    31
#>  8     2 2019-04-30    NA    61
#>  9     3 2019-01-31    NA     0
#> 10     3 2019-02-28     3     0
#> 11     3 2019-03-31    NA    31
#> 12     3 2019-04-30    NA    61
```

***Data:***

```r
df1 <- read.table(text="ID|  DATA     |  QTD
                        1 |2019-01-31 |   NA
                        1 |2019-02-28 |   3
                        1 |2019-03-31 |   NA
                        1 |2019-04-30 |   5
                        2 |2019-01-31 |   3
                        2 |2019-02-28 |   4
                        2 |2019-03-31 |   NA
                        2 |2019-04-30 |   NA
                        3 |2019-01-31 |   NA
                        3 |2019-02-28 |   3
                        3 |2019-03-31 |   NA
                        3 |2019-04-30 |   NA", 
                   header=T, sep="|")
```